# How to use HTTP Handler to make a client2client communication?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web, httphandler

I'm new to Web programming!
I try to make an app (something like Client to Client communication with C# Handlers and jQuery).

I.E.: 
When 1Client make a click on his clientSide(browser), there paints one point, and on the same time the 2Client sees what 1Client did. And, in turn, where 2Client make a click on his browser, there paints one point, and the 1Client also sees what 2Client did.

I could done already the configuration of IIS, I made an simple show Hello World and it run OK. 
And, further, what should i done....

Can you advice me, please, with some exemples, or tutorials, how to do this job.

Sorry for my questions which seems to be not studied.

Comment: you new to web programming and start with the hard ones ?

Comment: Aristos, as a task to learn Web Development I thought to do something like this..

Comment: if you like to learn web development, start with something simple and drop this one. Make a todo list.

Comment: The main problem here is to make the drawing on the page using canvas :) then the synchronize.

Comment: Aristos, maybe not to paint, but only to show some characters ... as a chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a chat like think. The simplest way that I can think.

First you have a table that keep all the chat lines that enters.
Then in a page you have two controls, one text box that users enter text, and one GridView that you show what is on the table.

All of that you place them on an UpdatePanel and you make an internal update to 2 seconds.

So every enter from the users you inserting to the table, and every insert you show to all users.

This is for start.

Answer (score 1):

you can use signalR for this !
It uses a long polling implementation to simulate websockets and it works rather well.

- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Quickstart example:

- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections

A more complex solution would be to use socket io with iisnode/node.js

- http://socket.io/
- https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/

Comment: thx, but i'd like to use only C# handlers, jQuery, HTML + CSS

Comment: signalR will work with that, you can install it into your c# project with little hassle from NuGet http://nuget.org/packages/signalr